# SingleThreadExecutor and ThreadFactory

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Am I right that every time, when we performing several submit operations:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(
            new MyThreadFactory("someExecutor"));
executor.submit(...);
executor.submit(...);
executor.submit(...);
```

Method `java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory#newThread` executes only once? Or it executes every time and creates a new thread per submit call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reuses the same thread everytime.

That is the beauty of thread pools: avoid the cost of creating a new thread by reducing the per-task invocation overhead.

You can read more about how threads are actually created in the [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at Executors code you see that it creates ThreadPoolExecutor with core and maximum threads set to '1' and keep alive time to 0:

```
public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor(ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
    return new FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService
        (new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
                                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(),
                                threadFactory));
}
```

The keep alive only monitors whether there is more then core threads, which is never the case here, since core is 1 and max is also 1. A new thread will be created only once and stay alive until you shutdown the executor via `shutdown` or `shutdownNow` method.

There is no magic in the shorthand way of creating `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `Executor` helper methods, just inspect the code there :)